# Xamarin XAML Binding Path with children

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I have a `ViewCell` with a `Picker` which is in `ListView`:

(Simplified)

```
    <ViewCell.View>
        <Label Text="{Binding CompanyName}"/>
        <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding ??this??.Employees}">
```

The ViewCell is bound to a `Company` which has a collection of `Employees`  (`Employee.Name` is the field value to show)

How do I set the Picker to the Employees. Bascially I need a `this.Employeess` ??

Comment: have you tried just "{Binding Employees}"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Since the list of Employees is part of the Company that is being Binded, you simple need to Bind the ItemsSource to the Employees

```
  <ViewCell.View>
        <Label Text="{Binding CompanyName}"/>
        <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
```